# dealing with service being destroyed

Tags: android, android-intent, service, location

Have a service running on the UI thread which wouldn't be my first approach with more time to get use to android and JAVA but don't have time to sort that.

I think the problem is when the system destroys the service it trys to restart but the original intent sent when starting it is causing a null pointer exception don't know if I should do something to save instances of the activity or do something in the service to solve the problem.

Just looking for the most painless way to insure it restarts for now if i can avoid multi threading that would be great. The section of code below has the line causing the problem.

sorry about the log-cat formatting

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "started");

    if(deviceId==null){
        Log.d(TAG, "in if");
        deviceId=intent.getStringExtra("device_id");
        contact=intent.getStringExtra("carers_num");
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "num =" +contact);
    Log.d(TAG, "id = "+deviceId);

    if(deviceId.equalsIgnoreCase("carersD")){
        Log.d(TAG, "The carers device has been selected");

    }else if (deviceId.equalsIgnoreCase("patientsD")) {

        Log.d(TAG, "The patients device has been selected");
        registerListener();
    }

    return START_STICKY; 
} 


03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.sblyit.finder.LocationService@41f6ee18 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2571)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1334)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at com.sblyit.finder.LocationService.onStartCommand(LocationService.java:83)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2554)
03-30 13:03:23.983: E/AndroidRuntime(25132):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

START_REDELIVER_INTENT seems to have solved the error for anyone having similar issue

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your service to be restarted, return `START_NON_STICKY`.

If you want to stop your service if intent doesn't contain appropriate data, call `stopSelf()`.

Comment: The thing is i do want to it to restart but I'm getting an error when it trys too. I think it to do with the content of the intent being lost when it gets destroyed causing a null pointer execution when it try's to restart

Comment: That's the second part of my answer though.

Comment: I used START_REDELIVER_INTENT I don't see that in your answer. New to this type of development if there is something I'm missing let me know. I only seen START_NON_STICKY and stopSelf() both of which do the opposite to what I was trying to do.